# Does this shape one cluster? and why angles change every time i run the code?

Tags: clustering, data-transformation, k-means, multidimensional-scaling

I have data and tried to do clustering on it. every time I run the code with the below statements it changes the angle of the shape but still the same below shape

```
mds = manifold.MDS(max_iter=200, eps=1e-4, n_init=1,dissimilarity='precomputed')
dp_mds = mds.fit_transform(dist)
```

Does that normal?

[image]

and Does this shape has more cluster?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in angles is due to the [random nature](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html) of `sklearn.manifold.MDS`. Change your code to

```py
mds = manifold.MDS(max_iter=200,
                   eps=1e-4,
                   n_init=1,
                   dissimilarity='precomputed',
                   random_state=0)

dp_mds = mds.fit_transform(dist)
```

Setting the `random_state` to any integer solves the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying , i will try it now .. but does the second image has two cluster ?

Comment: You should investigate further, using one manifold learning algorithm in these situations doesn't seem correct.